# .Net 4.5 WebSocket Server Running on Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7, websocket, .net-4.5

I know the ClientWebSocket class of .Net 4.5 is not supported on Windows 7, but is it possible to create a WebSocket server running on Windows 7 using the .Net 4.5 API?

To make myself clearer, according to both [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159274.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.aspx), it looks like the server side part of the .Net 4.5 WebSocket implementation should be supported even on Windows 7, yet running a HttpListener and trying to access it using an open-source WebSocket implementation got me a "Portocol not supported" error

Comment: While it is an _interesting_ question, it doesn't show much effort. What have you tried? According to MSDN indeed only Windows 8 and Server 2012 are supported. Do you require .NET built-in support? Otherwise there are various third-party libraries that suit your requirements.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The OS-level HTTP.SYS support for websockets is limited to Win8 / Windows Server 2012 - which I agree is silly (it should be part of a windows-update, or a service-pack at most, IMO).

This means that you can't use the framework support for WebSockets from `HttpListener` or ASP.NET directly.

But: as for "is it possible to create a WebSocket server" - sure... but only if you handle the TCP/IP comms yourself, or use a 3rd-party library for the same. This is a *little* annoying, but is not as bad as it might sound.

Edit: after some checking, I can confirm that the server-side components for this **do not** work on Windows 7 (etc); the `IsWebSocketRequest` returns `false` **even though** it is a web-socket request with `Connection: Upgrade` and `Upgrade: websocket` (etc) headers (from a Chrome session, as it helps).

I am, however, ***very surprised*** to find that the client-side pieces don't work, because: that is simpler and doesn't (or at least, doesn't *need to*) involve HTTP.SYS. Trying to use them throws a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Comment: To answer both your questions, while ClientWebSocket *is* supported only from Windows 8 onwards, the server-side classes are -at least according to the MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159274.aspx) - *are* supported

Comment: @sternr I don't think they are; I think it'll error at runtime. What is even more interesting: I was under the impression that `ClientWebSocket` **was** supported on Win7 etc, since it doesn't depend on HTTP.SYS!

Comment: @sternr did some more research / testing on that; answer stands.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts, this is all very akward at least from my - a simple user - point of view...

Comment: @sternr it is bizarre from my point of view too. I'm very disappointed by this, *especially* the client-side pieces. Meh, no actually I'm disappointed by the server-side pieces too.

Comment: Both the client-side and the server-side pieces depend on an OS-level component (websocket.dll), and this component only ships with Windows 8 / Server 2012.  I am unsure of why this component cannot run downlevel, but the dependency explains the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @Levi I just find it surprising; I've written a pure c# web-socket (all versions) client and server - it wasn't huge and didn't warrant OS-level support. The only way this makes sense to me is: for HTTPS support - that is, admittedly, a lot of extra work

Comment: Yeah, honestly, who thinks this is *really* a technical issue.

Comment: Its amazing the client doesn't work. Just got bitten by this when a developer (on windows 7) tried to run my very basic echo example. :O

Answer (score 7):

As Marc says, the Microsoft APIs do not work on Windows 7. However there are several open source libraries that support WebSockets on Windows 7, and in some cases even cross platform via Mono.

- https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck
- http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/
- http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the [System.Net.WebSockets documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.5):

> Some of the classes in the System.Net.WebSockets namespace are
>   supported on Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, and Windows Server 2008.
>   However, the only public implementations of client and server
>   WebSockets are supported on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. The
>   classes and class elements in the System.Net.WebSockets namespace that
>   are supported on Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, and Windows Server 2008
>   are abstract classes. This allows an application developer to inherit
>   and extend these abstract classes with an actual implementation of
>   client WebSockets.

In other words: DIY the actual implementation.