# ASP.NET MVC 4 and WebSockets

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a simple chat application using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Websockets based on the tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617611/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-1 . I am getting the following error when i try to execute the application.

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:19239/WebSockets/api/MvcWebSockets' failed: Unexpected response code: 404

My application's namespace : WebSockets
Name of the Controller which contains the code for handling the websockets server side is: MvcWebSockets

The code is exactly same as provided in the above mentioned link. Kindly help me understand this error?.

Comment: Are you using Windows 8? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073455/net-4-5-websocket-server-running-on-windows-7

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I didn't mention that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

the article suggest to use WCF for the websocket but I think that approach is old, not MS has a cooler library named SignalR that is really better, faster and has all the fallback you need.

Take a look to this page http://www.asp.net/signalr there are several articles about this argument.

.u