# ServiceStack: Choice of Server-Sent Events over WebSockets

Tags: websocket, servicestack, server-sent-events

Was looking at the latest release notes which mentions the new SSE Feature. This feature is definitely great to have and seems to be long-polling in reverse to the browser.

I am new to all of this but WebSockets seem to be the optimal way as it's bidirectional where SSE is only one-way to the browser. Plus IE doesn't support SSE but has supported WebSockets for the last two or three versions.

I was just wondering the reason for the choice of SSE over WebSockets.

Comment: As with your last question, this is off topic because you are asking questions directly to the ServiceStack team regarding their design decision to use SSE over websockets; for which **only they can speak authoritatively**. As already mentioned SO is not an alternative contact for direct access to ServiceStack. While Mythz has provided a good answer (+1), this is a question that should have been asked directly with ServiceStack by email or [through their support community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/109366152718539931747).

Comment: Got it. Thanks anyway Mythz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasons for supporting Server Sent Events are [outlined in the Chat demo project](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat#server-sent-events):

[Server Sent Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) (SSE) is an elegant [web technology](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) for efficiently receiving push notifications from any HTTP Server. It can be thought of as a mix between long polling and one-way WebSockets and contains many benefits over each:

- **Simple** - Server Sent Events is just a single long-lived HTTP Request that any HTTP Server can support
- **Efficient** - Each client uses a single TCP connection and each message avoids the overhead of HTTP Connections and Headers that's [often faster than Web Sockets](http://matthiasnehlsen.com/blog/2013/05/01/server-sent-events-vs-websockets/).
- **Resilient** - Browsers automatically detect when a connection is broken and automatically reconnects
- **Interoperable** - As it's just plain-old HTTP, it's introspectable with your favorite HTTP Tools and even works through HTTP proxies (with buffering and checked-encoding turned off).
- **Well Supported** - As a Web Standard it's supported in all major browsers except for IE which [can be enabled with polyfills](http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/#yaffle).

i.e. it's an beautifully simple and elegant [Web Standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) with a better HTTP fidelity than WebSockets, that's perfect fit for Server Push Communications that works in both ServiceStack' ASP.NET and SelfHosts without requiring any extra .NET dependencies or require the host Windows Server have WebSockets support enabled to use. IE Support [can be enabled with polyfills](http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/#yaffle).

WebSockets may be supported at a later date but that's likely to require additional external dependencies and requirements for a [Windows Server that supports WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12073593/85785).