# SignalR client on Windows Server 2008R2 using Server Sent Events

Tags: websocket, signalr

**Server:**  Windows Server 2012 with WebSocket support

**Client Machine 1:** Windows 8.1

**Client Machine 2:** Windows Server 2008R2

I built a C# application using the SigalR client that I can delpoy on my two client machines.  However, the issue that I am running in to is that `Client Machine 1` connects using WebSockets, and `Client Machine 2` connects using Server Side Events.

How can this be the case?  Clearly the server supports WebSockets since `Client Machine 1` can connect using them.  I don't understand how `Client Machine 2` would use SSE.

Using `hub.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;` on my client, I see:

```
20:57:01.5805156 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
20:57:02.1117656 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - WS Connecting to: wss://internal.soroco.com/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=webSockets&connectionData=[{"Name":"ClientDaemonHub"}]&connectionToken=Mvbkw1czN7OZSE1jcfFjC2elxYxJhZiTZwisKKn6ZzYv%2BXRjOgfkclRJdSQtPi2wy%2F7XsUyxbCEXPMesFjvE7zh0FrcGwEsh6WTpHlkqB0rXyARnC42Op8ZO3w%2FhuKcB
20:57:02.1273906 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - Auto: Failed to connect to using transport webSockets. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The WebSocket protocol is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.WebSocketTransport.<PerformConnect>d__1.MoveNext()
20:57:02.1273906 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - SSE: GET https://internal.soroco.com/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=serverSentEvents&connectionData=[{"Name":"ClientDaemonHub"}]&connectionToken=Mvbkw1czN7OZSE1jcfFjC2elxYxJhZiTZwisKKn6ZzYv%2BXRjOgfkclRJdSQtPi2wy%2F7XsUyxbCEXPMesFjvE7zh0FrcGwEsh6WTpHlkqB0rXyARnC42Op8ZO3w%2FhuKcB
20:57:02.1430156 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - SSE: OnMessage(Data: initialized)
20:57:02.1430156 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {"C":"d-752B7883-B,0|I,0|J,1","S":1,"M":[]})
20:57:02.4086406 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - ChangeState(Connecting, Connected)
20:57:03.5180156 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - OnMessage({"R":"497ca302-7375-4250-aa85-fb4ae2556877","I":"0"})
20:57:03.8461406 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - OnMessage({"I":"1"})
20:57:04.7523906 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
20:57:05.7523906 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - OnMessage({"I":"2"})
20:57:07.7367656 - 7ff6f37a-2485-4f08-9c20-872f63964bee - OnMessage({"I":"3"})
```

Looks like the relevant error is:

> Auto: Failed to connect to using transport webSockets. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The WebSocket protocol is not supported on this platform.

Comment: Are you building a windows store app?

Comment: Then webosckets should work assuming you are not doing PCL (portable class libraries). Turn on logging and you should see what is happening. You can also make sure that the server does really support websockets using the following trick - in your browser request the following page http://localhost:9999/signalr/negotiate (obviously replace localhost:9999 with your host) and check that the response (it will be JSon) contains `"TryWebSockets":true`.

Comment: The server definitely has WebSockets enabled, as when I run my C# application on a Windows 8.1 machine it connects over WebSockets.  However, when I run that same application on Windows Server 2008R2, it connects using Server Sent Events.  I need to read up on PCL and I'll try to enable logging. Thanks!

Comment: @Pawel I added my trace output on my client.

Comment: the logs you provided are after the connection has been started. Transport selection happens before that. I don't remember from the top of my head how extensive are client logs with this regard but in the worst case you should also be able to use fiddler to trace what's going on the wire. I wrote a post on SignalR protocol http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/ and the problem you are seeing happens when the connection is being started (see the start sequence in the post) so you need to look somewhere there.

Comment: @Pawel you are correct, I wasn't starting the trace until after the connection had been established.  I updated my output.  It says that WebSocket protocol is not supported on this platform.  That is from my C# client on Windows Server 2008R2

Comment: Crap - I missed that the client is on Win2008 thinking only about Windows 8.1. .NET Framework 4.5 on Win7 and Win2008 R2 doesn't support the `ClientWebSocket` class and this is what the SignalR client uses for websocket transport. Since using websocket fails the client falls back to ServerSentEvents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NET Framework 4.5 on Win7 and Win2008 R2 [doesn't support the `ClientWebSocket` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073455/net-4-5-websocket-server-running-on-windows-7) and this is what the SignalR client uses for websocket transport. Since using websocket fails the client falls back to ServerSentEvents.