# .NET ClientWebSocket with Java based WebSocket Server

Tags: java, c#, wpf, websocket

I have one WPF application, which needs to communicate with Java
 backend server. I thought creating the the WebSocket client from WPF
 application and WebSocket Server from Java backend.

Does .NET [ClientWebSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket(v=vs.110).aspx) supports using the Java based WebSocket Server.

Comment: Why asking, just try it first, if not working, then ask...

Comment: Right now I don't have any of the part from both side ready. I know theoretically if both have implemented the RFC standards then it should work. But I did not find any examples, if this is right choice.

Comment: The WebSocket implementation in .net is very OS specific. I think you'd be better off using a library implementation such as are shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25379860/6550457

Comment: @FloatingKiwi thank you that link is very helpful. I just need client side. I better off using the 3rd party library. .NET seems have created boundaries for this. Very surprising. The Nuget Package model of releasing new .NET features (like task library etc..) is useless for WebSockets.